# Remove unwanted queries using htaccess?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to remove both the language and currency parameters from URL using .htaccess

Example:

Now if switching to DE (for example) it will show:

```
mysite.com/de/
```

and even if translating to German I still want it to show:

```
mysite.com
```

same for currency, if changing this to EUR for instance it now shows:

```
mysite.com/index.php?currency=EUR
```

and I would like to show :

```
mysite.com
```

What should be added into .htaccess in order to accomplish this?

Currently my htaccess has this:

```
Options All -Indexes

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(de|en|es|fr|it|nl|pl)/(.+)?$ $2?lang=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: You do realize this changes how Apache actually processes the requests, not just how they look in the address bar, right? It sounds like instead you should be moving these localization settings into the session data.

Comment: If this is not applicable I would not mind beautifying the string index.php?currency=EUR to /eur so if selecting german and euro it would show mysite.com/de/eur but the problem is I dont want any SE indexing any of these two parameters. Despite the fact that I have added this into meta  <?php if (!empty($_GET['currency']) || !empty($_GET['lang'])) echo '<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">'; ?> it still indexes these.